# Replace string with special characters for empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say my string looks like this...

```
var find = '&roadmap=1';
```

I want to replace **all** instances of that string in my url to `''`.

`url.replace(find, '');` seems to throw :

```
uncaught typeerror: url.replace is not a function
```

I assume it's because of the special characters within the find string itself. So how can I remove all instances of `&roadmap=1` from my url?

Comment: Why is `url` type? Are you sure its _string_ literal?

Comment: `window.location.search` @Satpal

Comment: Post an example and its desired output!

Comment: Indeed `window.location.search` returns a string literal. Still seems something is missing

Comment: are you sure this isn't only a typo of using "url" instead of variable you loaded which is "find" ?

Comment: Is url a String? What is the **type** of url?

Comment: find the whole pages whether the `url` variable being assigned with unexpected value. It tooo weird when looking at the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
url.toString().replace(/&roadmap=1/g, '');
```

Comment: How this will work if _url.replace is not a function_?

Comment: @Satpal Is it better?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be regarding the type of `url`.
whatever `url` is, it's not a string. It has to be a string for the method `replace` to work on it.

You can use `console.log(typeof url);` to find out what it is.

You can learn more about types here: [JavaScript data types and data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Answer (score 0):

You should at least show us what variable `url` look like so that we can make sure it `typeof url // => "string"` because replace method is for String.